# PHP How to get rid of white spaces on Oracle 9i?

Tags: php, oracle9i

I am using Oracle 9i as my database. My problem is the columns of the this database supplies an ample amount of white spaces.
For Example:
Username with Char(100) if I insert a 5 character inside this column like *ADMIN* it will have 95 white space after the word *ADMIN*.

The problem now is that every time I query I needed to use TRIM inside my query or else it will not work.

For example : `SELECT COUNT(USERNAME) AS TOTAL FROM ASUSERACCOUNT WHERE TRIM(USERNAME) = :username`

Are there any configurations I need to make to remove whitespaces on my database?

Comment: How are you inserting the data?

Comment: @bassxzero just a normal way of inserting without white spaces. The problem with the oracle database is that it automatically adds the white space

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think oracle databases support any type of columns that automatically add whitespace to your data. Which is why I'm asking how you're inserting the data. Maybe there is a function/trigger running that is updating your data.

Comment: @bassxzero based on my experience with other database only in Oracle 9i I have experience this. When you access the data inside the database you can see that there is a white space automatically added

Comment: How is the column defined?

Comment: Why not use `VARCHAR2`? ~ https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:123212348063,#